# How to catch Exception from remote WCF service?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, exception, handle

After add the reference from Visual Studio UI, I initialized the client:

```
private WcfRequestProcessorClient _client;

var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;

string serviceFullUrl = "http://myserviceurl.com/svcapi";
var address = new EndpointAddress(serviceFullUrl);

_client = new WcfRequestProcessorClient(binding, address);
_client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "MyUserName";
_client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "MyPassword";
```

And later, I call the related method with the request as parameter:

```
try
{
    var itemsReq = LoadItemsRequest();
    _client.ProcessRequestsAsync(itemsReq);
}
catch(Exception)
{
     // source code for show an error in a popup
}
```

Now, when the URL, Username, and Password **are correct**, **all work fine**. But **if** URL, Username, or password **are wrong**, **the app breaks** and Visual Studio show me this window when debugging, **jumping my catch block**:

[image]

Which is the way to handle these type of exceptions?

Comment: That dialog is really helpful... Use the Call Stack window to obtain the call stack at this point. Include external code.

Comment: do you have the service code?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh, I don't have the service code. I only want to catch the exception in order to show some dialog. Is this possible?

Comment: try like this :` catch(Exception e){Console.WriteLine(e.Message;}`

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh nothing...I also have placed breakpoints inside some catch block lines and it doesn't stop.

Comment: try putting [HandleProcessCorruptedStatesException] attribute on your method.

Comment: You appear to be calling a async method without awaiting it, what happens if you do `await _client.ProcessRequestsAsync(itemsReq);` instead? (you will need to do async/await all the way up your call stack for it to work, if that is not doable switch to `_client.ProcessRequests(itemsReq);`)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, the method is not awaitable, it doesn't return a task (is just a void). I am subscribing to the ProcessRequestsCompleted event provided by the _client class.

Comment: Why haven't you obtained the call stack yet? Let's see where this exception actually happens.

Answer (score 0):

The Service needs to be configured to propagate the real exceptions back to you.

It does how ever state if an exception as be thrown even though you don't know the actual reason like you've stated. **'an Exception as been thrown'**

The reason the Exception is not caught  is that the call is asynchronous.

i.e. the exception is thrown on a different Stack then the one you called it on.

if it returns a Task you would need to await it.

if it's an APM style asynchronicity  you would have to provide a callback and attempt to catch it there.

Additionally you can register to [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://AppDomain.UnhandledException) to catch this exception eventually.

Comment: Hello. The method is not awaitable (it's just a void). I must to subscribe to the ProcessRequestsCompleted event. So...how can I do it?

Comment: what's ProcessRequestsCompleted ?. i suggested as much that you have to provide a callback if it's an APM style call. i don't remember how to do that . the answer still stands that the cause of the exception not being caught is the asynchronous nature of the call.

Answer (score 0):

```
catch(Exception e)
    {
     MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
    }
```

Hope this helps.
    For Advance exception throwing refer to FaultException in WCF. It is specially designed for Service Oriented Architecture.

Comment: Or use e.InnerException

Comment: Hello. My problem is that I am not catching the exception. I already have tried with FaultException... I have placed some breakpoints inside catch block and the debugger is not stopping. My goal is to handle the exception and avoid the app to be broken and closed automatically.

Comment: Check if the exception is not thrown outside your try catch block. It may be  the issue.